# Paypal Integration In Context Checkout

Tags: html, paypal

I was trying Paypal integration with the following code in my page

```
<form id="myContainer"  action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/xclick" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My painting" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" /> 

</form>
<script>
window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
    paypal.checkout.setup('UBNM79WLCPCP4', {
        environment: 'sandbox',
        container: 'myContainer'
    });
};
</script>
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

This is not redirecting me to the payment gateway instead I am redirected to the following URL
"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/home".

Can someone please guide me through the integration process and tell me where I am going wrong?